# Excel Find similar and different word in cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help on this;

I have 3 rows of animals in excel:

cat,dog,bird
dog,tiger,lion
bear,cat,dog

I would like to have 1 column that identify what animals that are similar in these 3 rows:

`dog`

and what animals are different from these 3 rows:
`cat,bird,tiger,lion,bear`

Can anybody help on the excel formula. Thanks!

Comment: `cat,dog,bird` are in one cell or 3 cell in same row.

Comment: cat,dog, bird are in one cell

Comment: perhaps find() with and()

Answer (score 3):

This set-up will depend upon there not being too many rows' worth of data to parse, else `TEXTJOIN` will surpass its character limitation.

Assuming data in `A1:A3`:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A1:A3,
    φ,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,ζ),","),
    ς,",",
    UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(φ,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(ζ)),N(ISERR(FIND(ς&φ&ς,ς&ζ&ς))))=0,"")))
)
```

Same formula for the words which are not common to all rows, though changing the part `=0` to `<>0`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, tried to avoid the use of `TEXTJOIN()` because of the character limitations, as sighted above by **[Jos Woolley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17007704/jos-woolley)** Sir. May be there is more room to improvise this, but I tried the following.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LET(
a,A1:A3,
b,DROP(REDUCE("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,",")))),1),
c,UNIQUE(TOCOL(b)),
TOCOL(BYROW(c,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(x,
AND(MMULT(N(x=b),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b),,,0))>0)))),3))
```

---

**Few Scenarios:**

[image]

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

---

**Similar words:**

We can just look at the first input.

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(d,",",x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,d),FILTER(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,AND(NOT(ISERR(FIND(d&y&d,d&A1:A3&d)))))),""))
```

---

**Non-similar words:**

We simply substitute `TEXTSPLIT(A1,,",")` with `UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTAFTER(","&TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3&",",",",SEQUENCE(,99)),",",-1),2))`. Furthermore we want to use `OR()` to check if any of the results through `FIND()` returns an error.

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(d,",",x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTAFTER(d&TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3&d,d,SEQUENCE(,99)),d,-1),2)),FILTER(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,OR(ISERR(FIND(d&y&d,d&A1:A3&d))))),""))
```

---

**Note:** As is, these formulas are case-sensitive!